# Safari sub-menu navigation bug

Tags: css, safari

For my navigation, I'm showing/hiding the sub-menus using height/width and opacity properties, rather than the display property, so that I can use CSS transitions to create a fade-in/fade-out effect for the sub-menus. This is working perfectly fine in every browser except for Safari, and I have no idea why.

The website is up at http://rtt.celero.com.au. Take a look at it in any browser other than Safari, and then compare to how it looks in Safari.

Other browsers:
[image]

Safari:
[image]

Anyone got any ideas about what's causing this bug in Safari?

EDIT: The website has been updated as per the `float: none` suggestion below, however now there seems to be another Safari-only issue, where the top-level navigation items are being expanded out to the width of the sub-menu. Any ideas on a fix for this?

New Safari issue:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will fix the issue in Safari

```
ul.menu li ul.sub-menu li{
    float:none;
}  
ul.menu li ul.sub-menu{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: That definitely seems to have helped, however now there seems to be another issue, where the top-level navigation items are being expanded out to the width of the sub-menu. Any ideas on how to fix that? I've updated http://rtt.celero.com.au with your fix so you can see the new problem.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, and seems like it's still working fine in other browsers. Thanks!